# On rails console output what does it mean #< on the following example?:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

On rails console output what does it mean `#<` at the start of the hash on the following example?:

```
irb(main):003:0> a=Movie.all
Movie Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" 
=> [#<Movie id: 1, title: "Aladdin", rating: "G", description: nil, release_date: "1992-11-25 00:00:00", created_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01", updated_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01">, #  <Movie id: 2, title: "The Terminator", rating: "R", description: nil, release_date: "1984-10- 26 00:00:00", created_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01", updated_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01">, #<Movie id: 3, title: "When Harry Met Sally", rating: "R", description: nil, release_date: "1989-07-21 00:00:00", created_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01", updated_at: "2013-07-27 21:29:01">,...  more output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how an object is printed in ruby, for example and instance of class Movie would be printed something like this:

```
<#Movie:0x003247fa... >
    |          |
   class      memory position I think
```

What you have there is a set of this previous writing:

```
[ one_object, other_object ... ]
```

To have a better display you could use [hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb).

Answer (score 0):

`#<` means that this is an instance of the Movie class.